# How to restrict access to my webpage

Tags: security, http, spring-security

I have a url to a search page (e.g. http://x.y.z/search?initialQuery=test).  It isn't a webservice endpoint, its just a basic url (which goes through a Spring controller).  There is no security around accessing page, you can enter the link in a browser and it will render results.

What I want is to find a way to prevent other sites from submitting requests to this url, unless they are specifically allowed.

I build a filter which would intercept all request to this page, and perform some validation.  If validation failed then they would be redirected to another page.

The problem is what validation to perform...  I tried using the referer field to see if the request was coming from an "allowed" site but I know the referer field isn't always populated and can easily be faked.

Is there a way to achieve this?

We also have IHS so if there is something that can be done in there either that would be great.

Comment: Is your web page intended for ANYONE to access, or just people who are logged in to your site?  Because if it's just for people who are logged in, you can just protect it from being accessed by anyone who's not logged in to your site...

Comment: I suggest that the user just wants suggestions for securing the page :/

Comment: @Coulton Our application is within a company.  The app has SSO, and basically all employees will pass SSO.  So its really anyone is allowed access the page.  The problem is I don't want other company sites linking to this page unless we have authorised that site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest implementing some kind of system to allow users to log in if you really want to protect a page from being accessed.

You could try to detect the IP address of the incoming request, but I'd imaging that this can be spoofed quite easily.

Realistically, pages that are public are open to any kind of interrogation to the limits that you set.  Perhaps limiting the data that the page returns is a more practical option?

This is the reason that website's like Facebook and Twitter implement [oAuth](http://oauth.net/) to prevent resources from being accessed by unauthorised users.

Answer (score 0):

How about you only run the result if the referring page has passed along a POST variable called "token" or something which has been set to a value that you give each app that's going to hit the search page. If you get a request for that page with a query string, but not POST value for "token", then you know its an unauthorized request and can handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IPs of sites which can contact your service, you can put Apache as a proxy and use [access control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) to permit/deny access to specific directories/urls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to avoid having your site "scraped" by bots, but do want to allow humans to access your search page.

This is a fairly common requirement (google "anti scraping"). In ascending order of robustness (but descending order of user-friendliness):

- block requests based on the HTTP headers (IP address, user agent, referrer).
- implement some kind of CAPTCHA system
- require users to log in before accessing the search URL

You may be able to buy some off-the-shelf wizardry that (claims to) do it all for you, but if your data is valuable enough, those who want it will hire mechanical turks to get it...

Answer (score 0):

make a certification security.
u can make self signed certification using openssl or java keytool
and u will have to send a copy of certificate to ur client.

If this client will not have this certificate, It will not be able to call ur service.

And to make certificate enable in ur web container.I dont know bout other containers but
in Apache tomcat, u can do it in connector tag of ur server.xml